# How to retrict date on UIDatePickerView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uidatepicker

hi guys can any body help me to figure out that how i can restrict the minimum date in `UIDatePickerView`? i tried to set property `minumumDate` from `xib` file but it is not working, even i set the the mode like this

```
[datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer];
```

but still it is not working. what i want to do is that user cannot scroll down from a specific date. example: if restricted date is `21.11.2011` then user should not scroll it to less then this date so please help me to figure it out

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you would want to set the mode to 'UIDatePickerDate', as 'UIDatePickerCountDownTimer' is meant to display a time. Have you tried:

```
[datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
[datePicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
```

minDate would be an NSDate with the restricted date. For info on how to initialize this date, see [here in the Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470). Especially the part about date components.

Comment: I also just tried it in xcode 4 using the 'xib' file, and it does work. Remember that in the Attributes inspector there are three dates you can set, the default date, the minimum date, and the maximum date. If you are going to use minimum or maximum, remember to also tick the box next to the constraint.